# Pausing from within a tkinter function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a couple of functions which do things in a sequential order. First they need to open a new window and display a label, then they need to wait for some seconds, then they need to call another function. However, I'm struggling to get the functions to wait, all the methods I've tried (.after, .sleep, .wait_visibility) seem to be ignored and it just skips to the next function call without pausing.

Here's what I have (sorry if it's messy, I'm new to python):

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root =Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

def scale_screen(event = None):
    global s_screen
    s_screen = Toplevel(root)
    s_screen.title('Residual Inhibition Tester')
    s_screen.geometry('600x600')
    s_screen.transient(root) 
    s_screen.bind('<Return>', sel)
    global var 
    var = IntVar()
    scale = Scale(s_screen, variable = var, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 1000)
    scale.focus_set()
    scale.pack(anchor=CENTER) 
    button = Button(s_screen, text="Select", command=sel)
    button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

def sel(event = None):
    label = Label(s_screen)
    selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)   
    interval_screen()

def interval_screen():
    global i_screen
    i_screen = Toplevel(root)
    i_screen.geometry('600x600')
    i_screen.transient(root)
    i_label = Label(i_screen, text = "Please Wait")
    i_label.pack(anchor = CENTER)
    s_screen.destroy()
    i_screen.after(3000, masker_screen) 
    #time.sleep(3)
    #i_screen.after(300,i_label.configure(text="Playing New Masker Noise")) 
    #root.wait_visibility(window = i_screen) 




def masker_screen():
    global m_screen
    m_screen = Toplevel(root)
    m_screen.geometry('600x600')
    m_screen.transient(root) 
    m_label = Label(m_screen, text = "Playing New Masker Noise").pack(anchor = CENTER)
    m_screen.after(3000, lambda: scale_screen(event = None))
    i_screen.destroy()

b1 = Button(root, command = scale_screen).pack(anchor=CENTER)
root.bind('<Return>', scale_screen)
root.mainloop()
```

In this example, the program will run but just skip the interval_screen entirely and just do the masker_screen. I'm also not averse to just using one screen and using the .configure methods to change the label text if that's easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [__runnable__ code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think it's possible to answer your question the way it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing all the ways you tried it, it's impossible to know what you did wrong. In general  you should never call `time.sleep` and you should never call `after` with just a single argument. Also, when you use `after` with two arguments, the second argument must be a reference to a function.

The proper way to do this is to have your first function call your second function via `after`:

```
def interval_screen():
    ...
    i_screen.after(3000, maker_screen)

def masker_screen():
    ...
    m_screen.after(3000, lambda: scale_screen(event = None))
```

Note that in your updated question you're using `after` incorrectly:

```
m_screen.after(3000, scale_screen(event = None))
```

You're calling the function `scale_screen(...)` immediately, and giving the result of that to the `after` function. If you need to pass arguments to your function you must create another function that does *not* require arguments. The simplest way to do this is with `lambda`, though you can also use `functools.partial` or you can create  your own function.

Comment: Hi Bryan thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I've tried this (I updated the question to show what I've done) and it's still skipping the waiting functions.

Comment: @Yoddlenod: if you look at your code you'll see you've done something wrong. See this line of code: `m_screen.after(3000, scale_screen(event = None))`. You're immediately calling `scale_screen(...)`, and the result of _that_ is being called by after. Look at the use of `lambda` in the last part of my example.

Comment: Ah, I see! That solves half the problem, thank you. But it still appears to be skipping over the interval_screen function. Even if I use the lambda function within the interval_screen.

Comment: @Yoddlenod: based on the code in the question now it can't  possibly skip over `interval_screen` because you're directly calling it, so I don't understand your comment. Also, you 're calling `masker_screen` twice - once directly, once via `after`.

Comment: Ahh! On a second run through and look, that seems to have solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help!